# EPM Project Server 2010 - PSI - Assign Project Permissions programmatically

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, psi, ms-project-server-2010

I am needing to assign permissions to a project when it is created. I already created an event that runs when a project is created, but I'm not finding what methods of the PSI to use to assign permissions to groups and users within the project.
To clarify, what I want to do is the same as is done in the "Project Permissions" section but programmatically.

If you can add a bit of code, I'll thank you.
Sorry for my English :P.

Thanks
Diego

Answer (score 0):

People and groups with their permissions come to Project through Security categories. In 2010 there are 2 kinds of the categories: Global categories defined in Server Settings -> Manage Categories and Project Category available through Project Permissions in Project Center. So this is about PWA.

For PSI all the things are available in WebSvcSecurity: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg221489(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg221489%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Key methods are:

- CreateCategories / CreateProjectCategories - to create any of this categories
- ReadProjectCategory / ReadCategory - to query the categories
- SetCategories / UpdateProjectCategories - to update the categories: add/remove users, grant/revoke permissions.